# Isomorphism question if base $\Delta$ for a root system is equal to the set of positive roots.

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

Let $\Delta$ be a base for a roots system $\Phi$ in $E$. I'm trying to prove that if $\Delta = \Phi^{+}$ then $(\Phi, E)$ is isomorphic to an orthogonal direct sum of copies of $(\{\pm 1\}, \mathbb{R})$.

I wish I had a strategy, but I don't. If anyone could drop a hint as to how to prove this, I would be grateful.

Comment: Hmm, that sort of depends on what facts we're allowed to use. But if $\Phi^+ = \Delta = \lbrace \alpha_1,..., \alpha_n \rbrace$ then $\Phi = \lbrace \pm \alpha_1,..., \pm \alpha_n \rbrace$ more or less by definition of $\Phi^+$. From which one gets $\Phi = \prod_{i=1}^n \lbrace \pm \alpha_i\rbrace$ (orthogonal product of root systems). What more would you need?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I'm new to this material, so it took me a while just to get a grasp on what I was working with. But yeah, I eventually made the same arguments.